# How can I remove all elements from a DXL skip list

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to clear all elements within a `Skip` list, like this:

```cpp
Module mod = current()
Skip skip = create()

put(skip, 1, "test")
put(skip, 2, mod)

clearSkip(skip) // Removes all elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setempty(Skip)` function, although this specific overload is undocumented as far as I know.

Comment: This depends on the content of your skip list. if both, key and value, contain simple or "DOORS" types (integer, string, Object, Module, Link etc.), you can just say `delete skip`, which will empty the list, and, for safety, `skip = null` so that you can later easily see whether `skip` is initialized. But if your list contains complex or custom types, like Arrays, structs or even Skip lists (of Skip lists of Skip lists), you have to write a specific delete function for these types, otherwise the contained elements will only be freed after your script ends.

Comment: @Mike I don't think it's the responsibility of a clear function to manage memory, it should be one of the programmer.

Indeed for normal types you could just delete the skip, but for this you need to know how the Skip was created — create() or createString() — when you wish to recreate it.

Comment: Oh, you're looking for the perm `void setempty (Skip)`?

Comment: @Mike You're right, I was. The DXL reference manual didn't mention that overload, only the one for `Buffer`. I tried searching for it as well, but couldn't find anything mentioning it.

Comment: one of the many undocumented dxl perms. See http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=473 or https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006HIM78/undocumented-perms-list (the latest version of Matthias' list is available at https://c.web.de/@337544526568622282/3CzAa5p0SlWz7SVmSJcqtw)

Answer (score 1):

example script for deleting Skips of custom types, here: type `OutLinkInfo`:

```
struct OutLinkInfo {}

OutLinkInfo createOutLinkInfo_() { DxlObject d = new(); OutLinkInfo x = (addr_ d) OutLinkInfo; return(x) }
DxlObject DxlObjectOf(OutLinkInfo x) { return((addr_ x) DxlObject) }

void deleteOutLinkInfo(OutLinkInfo &x) { DxlObject d = DxlObjectOf(x); delete(d); x = null; return() }
Skip deleteOutLinkInfo(Skip sk)
{
    OutLinkInfo x = null OutLinkInfo
    for x in sk do { deleteOutLinkInfo(x) }
    delete(sk); sk = null
    return(sk)
}
```